# PHPExcel help - How to Export data with PHPexcel in an custom table layout

Tags: phpexcel

I am quite new to PHPExcel and learning PHP as I go. I managed to get PHPexcel to export my data from SQL via the code below. Right now its just outputting in basic style, meaning its just serialized the data from SQL and next record would show up in the next row. I added an image of what I would like to accomplish, is this something possible with PHPexcel or am I dreaming.

If anyone could send me a quick example of how to accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Image
http://postimg.org/image/m3n60hn25/

Below is a working sample of a simple serialized export.

```
<?php

// connection with the database 
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "IMC_COE2"; 
$dbpass = "XXX"; 
$dbname = "IMC_COE2"; 

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass); 
mysql_select_db($dbname); 

// require the PHPExcel file 
require '/Excelphp/Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 

// simple query 

$query = 'SELECT client, team_name,support_team_prime,prime_comments,support_team_backup,backup_comments,escalation1,escalation1_comments,escalation2,escalation2_comments,escalation3,escalation3_comments,escalation4,escalation4_comments,note FROM tbl_address ORDER by team_name DESC'; 
$headings = array('Client Name','Team Name','Prime Contact','Comments','Backup Contacts','Comments','Escalation 1','Comments','Escalation 2','Comments','Escalation 3','Comments','Escalation 4','Comments','Additional notes'); 

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) { 
    // Create a new PHPExcel object 
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Users'); 

    $rowNumber = 1; 
    $col = 'A'; 
    foreach($headings as $heading) { 
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
       $col++; 
    } 

    // Loop through the result set 
    $rowNumber = 2; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
       $col = 'A'; 
       foreach($row as $cell) { 
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell); 
          $col++; 
       } 
       $rowNumber++; 
    } 

    // Freeze pane so that the heading line won't scroll 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2'); 

    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"'); 
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

   $objWriter->save('php://output'); 
   exit(); 
} 
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
```

UPDATE October 2nd:
Here is where I am at now, the only problem I have is that PHPExcel's export is only showing 1 record. I cant figureout the missing code that will show me all the records in the same format and cell array.

Image: 
http://postimg.org/image/8gicg5gtl/8a918f3e/

Heres my progress so far but still not getting a successful loop:

```
 <?php  
/** PHPExcel */  
require_once '/Excelphp/Classes/PHPExcel.php';  

// Create new PHPExcel object  
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

// Set properties  
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")  
->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")  
->setCategory("Test result file");  

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B2:D2');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B4:D4');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B7:D7');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B12:D12');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C3:D3');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B13:D13');  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3:D3')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C5:D5')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C6:D6')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C8:D8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C9:D9')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C10:D10')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C11:D11')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B13:D13')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(false);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(12);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(50);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(50);  

//Setting for borders   
$styleArray = array('borders' => array('outline' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => 'FFA0A0A0'),),),);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:B13')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C2:C13')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2:D13')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:D2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:D3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4:D4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B5:D5')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6:D6')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:D7')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B8:D8')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B9:D9')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B10:D10')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B11:D11')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B12:D12')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B13:D13')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

//Background color on cells 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2:D2')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFCCE5FF');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4:D4')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFCCE5FF');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:D7')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFCCE5FF');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B12:D12')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFCCE5FF');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:D7')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFCCE5FF');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B5')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B6')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B8')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B9')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B10')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B11')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE0E0E0');

    // Add some data  
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)  
                ->setCellValue('A1', '')   
                ->setCellValue('B1', '')  
                ->setCellValue('C1', '')  
                ->setCellValue('D1', '')  
                ->setCellValue('E1', '')
                ->setCellValue('A14', '')   
                ->setCellValue('B14', '')  
                ->setCellValue('C14', '')  
                ->setCellValue('D14', '')  
                ->setCellValue('E14', '')
                ->setCellValue('B3', 'Client:')
                ->setCellValue('B5', 'Prime:')
                ->setCellValue('B4', 'Support group contacts')              
                ->setCellValue('B6', 'Backup:')
                ->setCellValue('B7', 'Escalations') 
                ->setCellValue('B8', 'Escalation 1:') 
                ->setCellValue('B9', 'Escalation 2:') 
                ->setCellValue('B10', 'Escalation 3:') 
                ->setCellValue('B11', 'Escalation 4:') 
                ->setCellValue('B12', 'Notes');      

    //  SQl database connections
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "IMC_COE2", "IMC123");  
    mysql_select_db("IMC_COE2",$db);  

    $sql="select client, team_name,support_team_prime,prime_comments,support_team_backup,backup_comments,escalation1,escalation1_comments,escalation2,escalation2_comments,escalation3,escalation3_comments,escalation4,escalation4_comments,note from tbl_address ORDER by team_name";  
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);  
        if ($numrows>0)  
        {  
            $row=2;  
            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)              
                            ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $data['client'])  
                            ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $data['team_name'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+3), $data['support_team_prime'])  
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+3), $data['prime_comments'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+4), $data['support_team_backup'])  
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+4), $data['backup_comments'])  
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+6), $data['escalation1'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+6), $data['escalation1_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+7), $data['escalation2'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+7), $data['escalation2_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+8), $data['escalation3'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+8), $data['escalation3_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($row+9), $data['escalation4'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($row+9), $data['escalation4_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('B'.($row+10), $data['note']); 
            }  
        }          

    // Rename sheet  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Directory Tool Full dump');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5) 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export-Directory Tool.xls"'); 
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter->save('php://output');  
    exit;  
    ?>
```

Comment: It's perfectly possible to do in PHPExcel; you can store data in whatever cells you want; you can merge cells and style them for the headings, etc.... but nobody is actually going to write this for you

Comment: If someone has any examples that matches something like that table if would be great. Cant seem to find an example close to what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Specify just what problems you're having. Are you having problems with merging cells? Are you having problems with styling?

Comment: Actually im quite new to PHP and more with PHPexcel, im not understanding the coding structure that would be required for PHP excel to fill a table with data, skip a cell and fill the next table with data and so on. I just need to see a full working example of this so I can work from that.

Comment: A table or a cell? Excel really doesn't have a concept of a table at all, unless you're talking about pivot tables; but you specify exactly what cell you want to write to in the worksheet using the `$col.$rowNumber` value in your call to `setCellValue()`

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah I meant to say cell. Its just the way I made the structure i think of it as a table. Ill experiment with the functions you gave me, how would phpexcel recognize to import the next record to the next cell box (in lack or better words *table*)? I have about 300 entries just need to know if i need to target a specific cell for each of those entries.

Comment: You have a few methods you can use: most (like `setCellValue()`) are for setting data in a single cell, but you also have a fromArray() method that can be used to set a whole block of cells in a single call from an array (such as a row read from a database)

Comment: Thanks Mark really do appreciate the help, ill go and play around with the code and see what I get.

Comment: Hi Mark, I maged to get very close to my end result using the setCellvalue() method however I am only getting one record at a time. Im guessing its because i should be using the fromArray() method instead, would you be able to provide some feedback on that? I am very close to get this done :) would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Start using a $row variable, and setting cell values for cell `'B'.$row)`, `'C'.($row+1)` etc, incrementing $row by 12 each iteration... so that the row is being set dynamically

Comment: Using ->setCellValue('B2'.$row+1, $data['team_name']) crashes by PHPExcel tried ->setCellValue('B2'.$row, $data['team_name']) loads but still only shows a single record and not looping. I might be putting the $row variable int he wrong section most probably. I updated the main post with the code. Would you know what i am missing?

Comment: Basic PHP string concatenation: you're including the number in the literal string, and you're missing the brackets - `'B'.$row+1` should be `'B'.($row+1)` because you need to do the addition before the concatenation to get `B3` as the cell address when the value of $row is `2`

Comment: Thank you Mark, I really appreciate your feedback. I am following your advice however my data is spreading everywhere or my report crashes and its still only showing one record at a time. I am obviously messing up the proper way to loop the data. In my head when i read the code I updated above, i see it as start on $row=2 and while its fetching everything from SQL dump the data on the appropriate cell (example C2) and dump the next data on the next 13th row and so on. ->setCellValue('C2'.($row+13), $data['client']) I dont think im understanding the logic or the proper structure of this loop.

Comment: The cell address is a simple PHP string.... it's nothing clever. All you're doing is using normal PHP string concatenation to create a string with a cell address. If the value of `$row` is `2`, and you do `->setCellValue('C2'.($row+13), $data['client'])` the concatenation gives cell address `C215`. Use `->setCellValue('C'.($row+13), $data['client'])` and you'll get the correct cell `C15`

Comment: Ah thats what I was missing, ok I got it to fill in my data correctly however i'm still not getting the loop. Its only showing me 1 record at a time. Did I overlook something? Updated my code in the edit.

Comment: Yes, you missed incrementing the value of `$row` in the `while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))` loop

Comment: You'll also want to set your titles/styles/merges inside that loop as well, not just outside the loop where they're hard-coded cell references for the first data record

Comment: And you don't need to set cell values to an empty string; they're already empty cells until you set them to be something else

Comment: Ah perfect thank you Mark one more question if you dont mind. How would i set concatenation for this:$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B4:D4') I tried this but crashes by report $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($row+2):'D'.($row+2))

Comment: The `colon` (`:`) is part of the string literal, not a PHP operator - `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($row+2).':D'.($row+2))`

Comment: Your da man! Looks like I gotta work on looping my formatting as well. But I think its will be as simple as copying the similar coding structure as my data loop. Ill post my code to share with everyone once im done. Again thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final result, still needs tweaking but big thanks to Mark Baker who helped me out. It takes about 1-2 minutes to load the excel file but it works. I gonna figure out how to optimize the code for best performance.

```
<?php  
/** PHPExcel */  
require_once '/Excelphp/Classes/PHPExcel.php';  

// Create new PHPExcel object  
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

// Set properties  
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")  
->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")  
->setCategory("Test result file");  

$rows=2;

//This is the hard coded *non dynamic* cell formatting
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(12);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(50);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(50);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(85);

    //  SQl database connections
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "IMC_COE2", "IMC123");  
    mysql_select_db("IMC_COE2",$db);  

    $sql="select client, team_name,support_team_prime,prime_comments,support_team_backup,backup_comments,escalation1,escalation1_comments,escalation2,escalation2_comments,escalation3,escalation3_comments,escalation4,escalation4_comments,note from tbl_address ORDER by team_name";  
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);  
        if ($numrows>0)  
        {  

            while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
            {  

                //This section is the actual data import fromt he SQL database *dont touch*
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)              
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+1), $data['client']) //this will give cell C2. 
                            ->setCellValue('B'.$rows, $data['team_name']) // this will give cell B2 
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+3), $data['support_team_prime']) //this will give C5 
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+3), $data['prime_comments'])  // This will give D5
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+4), $data['support_team_backup'])  //This will give C6
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+4), $data['backup_comments']) //This will give D6 etc...  
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+6), $data['escalation1'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+6), $data['escalation1_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+7), $data['escalation2'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+7), $data['escalation2_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+8), $data['escalation3'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+8), $data['escalation3_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+9), $data['escalation4'])
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+9), $data['escalation4_comments'])
                            ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+11), $data['note']); 

                //Row height adjustments
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+3)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+4)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+6)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+7)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+8)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+9)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getRowDimension($rows+11)
                    ->setRowHeight(100);    


                //Cell Merging 
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.$rows.':D'.$rows);  
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.($rows+2).':D'.($rows+2));  
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.($rows+5).':D'.($rows+5));  
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.($rows+10).':D'.($rows+10));  
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C'.($rows+1).':D'.($rows+1));
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.($rows+11).':D'.($rows+11)); 

                //Cell Wraptext
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+1).':D'.($rows+1))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+3).':D'.($rows+3))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+4).':D'.($rows+4))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+6).':D'.($rows+6))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+7).':D'.($rows+7))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+8).':D'.($rows+8))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.($rows+9).':D'.($rows+9))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+11).':D'.($rows+11))->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

                //Background color on cells 
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$rows.':D'.$rows)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+2).':D'.($rows+2))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+5).':D'.($rows+5))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+10).':D'.($rows+10))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF9BC2E6');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+1))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+3))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+4))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+6))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+7))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+8))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.($rows+9))->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFE6F1FA');

                // Add some data  
                    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)  

                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+1), 'Client:')
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+3), 'Prime:')
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+2), 'Support group contacts')                 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+4), 'Backup:')
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+5), 'Escalations') 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+8), 'Escalation 1:') 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+7), 'Escalation 2:') 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+8), 'Escalation 3:') 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+9), 'Escalation 4:') 
                        ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+10), 'Notes');                



                $rows+=14; 
            }  
        }          

    // Rename sheet  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Directory Tool Full dump');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5) 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export-Directory Tool.xls"'); 
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter->save('php://output');  
    exit;  
    ?>
```